# Function storytelling scrollwebsite

Tags: javascript, function, variables

So for school i'm gonna make a storytelling website. But i need to write a function, but have no clue how to do it. I just started with javascript. I can read it, but have trouble writing it.

This is the case: I got an element. When the element is 1500px from the top. I want to change the css of this element from position: absolute to position: fixed. I know (think) i need the following variables.

```
var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    elemTop = $(elem).offset().top,
    distance = (elemTop - docViewTop);
```

But how to write a function and if and else statement with this. Cause i wanna do this for more elements i use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. You can alter a DOM element's CSS properties by accessing its style property. So, if you have a div with ID 'myDiv', then you could give it a position:fixed with this code

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.position = "fixed";
```

So, I'd recommend making a simple function that follows this pattern:

```
var changePosition = function (domElement, offsetFromTop) {  
  if (offsetFromTop >= 1500) {
    domElement.style.position = "fixed"; 

  } else {
    domElement.style.position = "absolute";
  }
}
```

Make sense?

Comment: Thanks! This is what i was searching for!